MQ2 Gas sensor ppm output incorrect
I wanted to create a custom PCB involving an MQ2 gas sensor and ppm concentration, and based my code on this website: https://www.exploreembedded.com/wiki/Interfacing_Gas_Sensor_(MQ2)_With_AVR
I'm using an STM32F030F4P6 MCU and STM32CubeIDE for the project so I had to convert their code to the STM32 IDE. The code I wrote can be seen below:
#include "main.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;


uint16_t ADCval;
char msg [100];
float LPGCurve[3]  = {2.3,0.20,-0.45};
float SmokeCurve[3] ={2.3,0.53,-0.43};
float Ro =  10;
#define LPG  (0)                     //Gas identity number macro
#define Smoke (1)                    //Smoke identity number macro
#define Rl_Value (10)                //Load resistor on MQ2 board macro
#define Ro_Clean_Air_Factor (9.83)   //(Sensor resistance in clean air)/Ro macro
float SensorCalibration(ADCval);

int GetPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, float *pcurve);
int GetGasPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, int gas_id);
float ReadSensor(ADCval);
float ResistanceCalculation(ADCval);
float SensorCalibration(ADCval);


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{


  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();


  sprintf(msg, "Calibrating Sensor... \r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  Ro = SensorCalibration();



  sprintf(msg, "Calibrating is complete \r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  sprintf(msg, "Ro: %0.5fkohm \r\n", Ro);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);


  while (1)
  {
       HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
       ADCval = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
       HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100);
       ADCval = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

       sprintf(msg,"%hu", ADCval);
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

       sprintf(msg, "   LPG: %3d ppm",GetGasPercentage(ReadSensor()/Ro, LPG));
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

       sprintf(msg, " Smoke: %3d ppm \n\r",GetGasPercentage(ReadSensor()/Ro, Smoke));
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

       HAL_Delay(100);
  }

}

float ResistanceCalculation(ADCval)
{
 return ( ((float)Rl_Value*(4095-ADCval)/ ADCval));
}

float SensorCalibration(ADCval)
{
 int i;
 float val=0;

 for (i=0;i<50;i++) {

 val += ResistanceCalculation(ADCval);
 HAL_Delay(500);

}
 val = val/50;
 val = val/Ro_Clean_Air_Factor;
 return val;
}

float ReadSensor(ADCval)
{
  int i;
  float rs=0;

  for (i=0;i<5;i++) {

  rs += ResistanceCalculation(ADCval);
  HAL_Delay(50);                                   //0.5 sec delay
 }
  rs = rs/5;
  return rs;
}

int GetGasPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, int gas_id)
{
  if ( gas_id == LPG ) {
  return GetPercentage(rs_ro_ratio,LPGCurve);

  } else if ( gas_id == Smoke ) {
  return GetPercentage(rs_ro_ratio,SmokeCurve);
  }

  return 0;
}


int  GetPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, float *pcurve)
{
 return (pow(10,( ((log10(rs_ro_ratio)-pcurve[1])/pcurve[2]) + pcurve[0])));
}


The output I'm getting from the PuTTY terminal:

When I put my lighter near the sensor I get an extremely large value, and I'm not exactly sure why this is. I realized their code had a typo with the GetPercentage Function as they used curve instead of curve which they were using as a pointer to store the value of that particular point of the curve. I realized too for the functions I had to start the ADC channel each time as the functions do not depend on the main, and I fixed the UART transmit and print functions I had previously.
What I am still confused about is why my values seem to be so off, along with why they are storing the GAS and SMOKE IDs as macros, I understand that the resistor calc is based on the ADC values along with the load resistor on the board, and how the functions are taking multiple samples and averaging them, however I can't tell if something is still off with my code or the hardware itself.
Also I am aware that these functions should be in a separate c file however I want to make sure the code works first before cleaning it up as I am still very new to c programming.

ResistanceCalculation() does not handle the case, where ADCval is zero. Division by zero may produce funny things on a microcontroller. Are you sure, that you connected the ADC to the analog output of the sensor board?

@Jens Should I put in an if statement that the ResistanceCalculation() only performs said function if ADCval>0? And yes I am positive that my sensor is getting 5V and the analog output is connected.

Did you read the datasheet of the sensor very carefully? Did you preheat the sensor for more than 24 hours? The sensor seems to be used only for detection but not for measuring a gas concentration.

Yes, write extra code for very small or zero ADCVal values and write a note via UART. These big numbers smell like a div by zero error.

So I outputted the ADCval on the terminal just to see if it was zero, and it seems to be reading it just fine and can go up to 4095, when I put the lighter near the gas sensor and press it it jumps to 4095 immediately, which then shows the large numbers on the terminal.
The datasheet I did read, though I found some of it confusing regarding the gas concentration curve, if the sensor can only be used for detection but not concentration, then would it make sense that the ADCval jumps to 4095 as soon as I bring the lighter near it?

@Jens Nevermind you are correct it is outputting a 0 even with the given if statement I added.

@Jens I think I see the problem with the way they have the formula configured your subtracting the ADC maximum value (4095) from the ADC reading and since this sensor jumps to 4095 when a lighter is present it causes the formula to output a 0 resulting in those really large numbers. So based on this fact is ppm readings even possible for this? I don't understand how I saw people do it on Youtube with the same Mq2 gas sensor breakout board.

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Well, ppm is part per million, but your lighter nearly replaces the air by a butan/propan mix, so you provide > 200,000 ppm easily. The sensor is not made for this range. Anyway, check the value of R1. Are there 10 kohm between ADC input and GND? The datasheet specifies Rmin = 300 ohm, so you should not reach a reading of 4095.

Since the function ResistanceCalculation(int ADCval) ignores the given ADCval parameter and makes a local measurement, all the ADC readings before calling ResistanceCalculation() are useless. This, however, is not an error, just bad code.

@Jens I checked the value of R1 it's 17k on the breakout board that I have, so I changed the code appropriately. Also, how do I make the ADC readings before ResistanceCalculation() valid? Should I not start the ADC in each function and use ADCval as a pointer and call it in the other functions? Is there any other lighter or device I can use that would have a smaller ppm range?

A secret trick from the gas detector manufacturing industry is to mix down concentrations in a plastic bag. 1 part concentrated gas to X parts air. Use a syringe. Your biggest issue is that you don't know the concentration of butane/propane in the lighter gas, so you don't know the final concentration. Also those detectors are crazy cross sensitive, as you can see from the datasheet so you need to be very careful when you're trying to get accurate values.

Also, they're very sensitive to changing temperature and humidity, so you need to compensate for that if you make want to get any reliable accurate readings. Don't get it exposed to liquid water for very long, for instance. And exposure to high concentration gas will degrade the  performance permanently, as well.

@Jens see updated code, attempting to fix the issues above but still struggling to get proper ppm output, ADC value is present but ppm is still 0.

Your last changes made things worse, e.g. the calibration function never invoked an ADC conversion and the averager function calls the ADC conversion only once.
I think, it would be better to calculate an average value out of a number of ADC samples (see adc_avr_val) and calculate the resistance value only once after the sampling loop.
You may try this demo code, however it may contain errors, because it has not been compiled.
If the calibration function returns an Ro of zero, the code does not work at all. This is still not properly handeled here.
#include "main.h"   //Main header file
#include <stdlib.h> //Standard library header file since we use a logarithmic function
#include <stdio.h>  //Standard header filer
#include <string.h> //String header filer
#include <math.h>   //Standard math header file for pow function

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

uint16_t BATval;
float Voltage;
float BATVoltage;
float result_ratio;
uint16_t adc_avr_val;
char msg [100];
float LPGCurve[3]   = {2.3, 0.20, -0.45};
float SmokeCurve[3] = {2.3, 0.53, -0.43};
float Ro =  10;

#define LPG  (0)                     // Gas identity number macro
#define Smoke (1)                    // Smoke identity number macro
#define Rl_Value (10.0)              // Load resistor on MQ2 board macro
#define Ro_Clean_Air_Factor (9.83)   // (Sensor resistance in clean air)/Ro macro

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);

static void uart_send_str (const char* msg) {
    HAL_UART_Transmit (&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

static int GetPercentage (float rs_ro_ratio, float *pcurve)
{
    float tmp = log10 (rs_ro_ratio) - pcurve[1];
    tmp = tmp / pcurve[2] + pcurve[0];
    return (pow (10, tmp));
}

static int GetGasPercentage (float rs_ro_ratio, int gas_id)
{
    if ( gas_id == LPG ) {
        return GetPercentage (rs_ro_ratio, LPGCurve);
    } else if ( gas_id == Smoke ) {
        return GetPercentage (rs_ro_ratio, SmokeCurve);
    }
    return 0;
}

static float ResistanceCalculation (uint16_t ADCval)
{
    if (ADCval <= 3) {
        // just noise, sensor not conducting
        return Rl_Value * 10000.0;
    }
    return ((Rl_Value * (4095 - ADCval) / ADCval));
}

static float ReadSensor (uint32_t sample_count, int pause_ms)
{
    uint32_t i;
    uint16_t ADCval;
    uint32_t ADCsum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sample_count; i++) {
        HAL_ADC_Start (&hadc1);
        //   ADCval = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); probably not needed
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion (&hadc1, 100);
        ADCval = HAL_ADC_GetValue (&hadc1);
        ADCsum += ADCval;
        HAL_Delay (pause_ms);
    }
    adc_avr_val = ADCsum / sample_count;
    return ResistanceCalculation (adc_avr_val);
}

static float SensorCalibration (void)
{
    float val = ReadSensor (50, 500);
    val /= Ro_Clean_Air_Factor;
    return val;
}

int main (void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    // insert delay for heater here..
    sprintf (msg, "Calibrating Sensor... \r\n");
    uart_send_str (msg);
    Ro = SensorCalibration();
    sprintf (msg, "Calibrating is complete \r\n");
    uart_send_str (msg);
    sprintf (msg, "Ro: %0.5f kohm \r\n", Ro);
    uart_send_str (msg);
    while (1)
    {
        result_ratio = ReadSensor (5, 50) / Ro;
        sprintf (msg, "ADCraw: %hu", adc_avr_val);
        uart_send_str (msg);
        sprintf (msg, "LPG   : %3d ppm", GetGasPercentage (result_ratio, LPG));
        uart_send_str (msg);
        sprintf (msg, "Smoke : %3d ppm\n\r", GetGasPercentage (result_ratio, Smoke));
        uart_send_str (msg);
        HAL_Delay (500);
    }
}


thank you for the sample code, it seems like I still have a lot to learn regarding programming...

Update me if there are issues. It is possible, that we have to force the compiler to use a floating point division in ResistanceCalculation() by writing (4095.0 - ADCval).
